# How to Export Dictionary Data to CSV

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new in python and I've been trying to save result of dictionary to csv file. However, I got an error which I dont know what it is. I used the search bar searching for similar case/recommended solution but still blur. Kindly share any insights and idea. Thanks in advance.

```
with open('hologram.csv','w') as f: 
f.write(",".join(['filename'] + [*res]) + "\n") 
for imgpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR, "*.png")):
    res = send_request_holo(imgpath)
    f.write(",".join([os.path.basename(imgpath)] + [*res.values()]) + "\n")  
    print(res)
```

The expected output in csv should be like this:-

| filename | hologram_scores | hologram |
| --- | --- | --- |
| img1. | 0.0052322322 | False |
| img2. | 0.00. | False |
| img3. | 0.0086543111 | False |
| img4. | 0.0052331209 | True |

Here is the error
[image: Error code]

Here is when printing the result (this is the one that need to be exported to csv)
[image: Print result]

Comment: what is `res`? are there float values?

Comment: Yes, it is float values (the one in 2nd picture)

Comment: in this line
`f.write(",".join(['filename'] + [*res]) + "\n") `
you are trying to add array of string to array of floats, thats not gonna work

Comment: if you want to print csv, you should loop through your 'lines' of data and print line by line

Comment: Do like this, ```[str(res['hologram_scores']), str(res['holograml'])]``` instead of ```[*res.values()]```. Basics of Python.